# font is not linked or embedded but console is without error

Tags: html, css, fonts

```
body{
    font-family: "open sans";
}
```

This is all I have about fonts. There is no link inside `head` tag, there is no `font face` inside css and I'm expecting some error in the console (Chrome).

But the console is clear. Inspecting any element it shows `font family: "open sans"` (inherited from the `body`).

Does that mean that browser has installed `open sans` by itself?

Comment: console debugs JavaScript not CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Fundamentals

- Console only debugs JavaScript, CSS fails silently.
- There are **[CSS linters](https://cssnewbie.com/best-active-css-lint-tools/#.W77NGWhKjDc)** available.
- "Open Sans" font is available from **[Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans)** -- to load them, place the following in the `<head>`:

> ```
> <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
> ```

- Next place the following CSS ruleset in either an external stylesheet or in a `<style>` block (**Note:** The value is wrapped in quotes and 90% of the time in title case (i.e.  first letter of each word is capitalized)):

> ```
> /* This is the most basic of requirements -- see demo for a better set of CSS rules */
> selector {font-family: 'Open Sans'}
> ```

---

### Demo

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    html {
      font: 400 16px/1.5 'Open Sans';
    }
    
    body {
      font-size: 1.1rem
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>Open Sans</h1>
  <p>Apparently we had reached a great height in the atmosphere, for the sky was a dead black, and the stars had ceased to twinkle. By the same illusion which lifts the horizon of the sea to the level of the spectator on a hillside, the sable cloud beneath
    was dished out, and the car seemed to float in the middle of an immense dark sphere, whose upper half was strewn with silver.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it change the font of the text? if not it will just read the `font family: "open sans"` as a normal style but wont affect anything.